# Renaming a file by passing an awk output on a *.tsv file

Tags: awk, mv

Have data and `*.tsv` file where data is described.
Would like to use the description and rename the data accordingly.

Please have a look :

- `awk` command to filter the tsv give this:

  ```
    common_voice_en_22090684.mp3 four
    common_voice_en_22090691.mp3 no
    common_voice_en_22090696.mp3 one
  ```
- go through the directory where the `*.mp3` are:

  ```sh
  for i in *.mp3 ; do
  echo $i
  ```
- `mv` is command to rename the file and it takes two arguments (the file to change, and with what)

How to use `awk` (to read and use the description) and `mv` (to rename the existing files with the passed description? So, looking at the above example, the result would be :

```
four.mp3    
no.mp3  
one.mp3
```

It is not important to use the suggested commands.
Any ideas, suggestions how to do this are most welcome!

Comment: If any of the answers here does what you want then see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

Comment: Your script is not `done`. Did you test it?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want something like this after saving output of *awk command to filter the tsv* in file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

for i in *.mp3
do
    new_name="$(awk -v name="$i" '$1 == name {print $2}' file)"
    if [ -n "$new_name" ]
    then
        echo mv -- "$i" "$new_name"
    fi
done
```

Remove `echo` to actually perform renaming but run it first with it to
make sure that it will what you need. Also notice that there is a
small chance that `mv` will fail because the original file will be
already deleted by the time the script execution reaches that line -
you can use `set -e` to exit immediately after the first `mv` fails.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't meet your requirement, but if you expect to process many files, you might get better performance by using your .tsv as the driver instead of a shell expansion, because you won't open the tsv once per mp3. Remove the `echo` if it looks like it would do what you expect.

`$ while read -r src tgt; do [ -f "$src" ] && echo mv -i "$src" "$tgt.mp3"; done < file.tsv`